# What's causing this strange random number generator behaviour?

Tags: r, plyr, rcpp

I'm trying to make some reproducible examples for some simulation studies, so I'm using `set.seed` to get consistent results from the "random" part. However, I noticed I was sometimes getting different results.

I've tried to narrow this down to a minimal reproducible example, but it seems to take multiple elements to trigger the bug.

This is what should happen:

```
library(RcppExamples)

set.seed(1)
RcppRNGs(3)
#        rnorm         rt rpois
# 1 -0.6264538  1.5144787     1
# 2  0.1836433 -0.3536704     0
# 3 -0.8356286 11.4386179     1
rnorm(3)
# [1]  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026
```

---

This code seems to be what activates the bug:

```
library(plyr)
S <- llply(1:100, function(.) Sys.sleep(1), .progress="text")
# |==========================                                        |  25%
```

Note that:

1. I've hit the "stop" button before `llply` finishes.
2. I know that you'd normally use `rlply` in this situation, but that doesn't trigger the bug.

Now here's what happens:

```
set.seed(1)
RcppRNGs(3)
#        rnorm         rt rpois
# 1 -0.6264538  1.5144787     1
# 2  0.1836433 -0.3536704     0
# 3 -0.8356286 11.4386179     1
rnorm(3)
# [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286
```

I should be getting the same results as I did in the first example, but `rnorm` is giving me different numbers.

The problem seems to be that Rcpp is no longer affecting the random number seed:

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(3)
# [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286
```

Given all the interacting parts here, who should I file the bug report with?

---

Here's my `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.1         RcppExamples_0.1.6 Rcpp_0.11.3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: For those of us who don't use `llply`, can you explain what a "stop" button is and what it does?  There's nothing in the sequence of commands that you did post which show what's happening.   All I can offer is: if you've got something that you terminated, perhaps your `exactRLRT` call is terminating at start, thus *not* causing and change in the  sequence of random numbers being generated.

Comment: There's a stop button in RGui and Rstudio. I think you can do the same thing with Ctrl-C if you're running R from a terminal.

Comment: OH so you completely interrupted a running function, leaving $deity knows what detritus around.   So anyway, what is the value of `x` (and fml1 for that matter) in each case?

Comment: @Pascal if that were the case the top example posted wouldn't happen. (?)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It happens to me running the top example. I don't get the same result for `rnorm(3)`.

Comment: I dont understand what the issue is here. set the seed again. plus you claim to want reproducibility but hitting stop at an arbitrary time isn't reproducible

Comment: I don't think that hitting stop should mean that half an hour later I'm getting different RNG behaviour.

Comment: how is that different than saying "why does `set.seed(1); rnorm(1); rnorm(1)` give me different random numbers?"

Comment: `set.seed(1); rnorm(1); rnorm(1)` should give me the same two random numbers every time I call it - that's the point of calling `set.seed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`llply` goes down to `loop_apply` which eventually calls this function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List loop_apply(int n, Function f) {
  List out(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    out[i] = f(i + 1);
  }

  return out;
}
```

So, as part of the business of `Rcpp::export` we get a call to `enterRNGScope`

```
    // [[Rcpp::register]]
    unsigned long enterRNGScope() {
        if (RNGScopeCounter == 0) GetRNGstate();
        RNGScopeCounter++;
        return RNGScopeCounter ;
    }
```

and at the end of `loop_apply` we are supposed to get a call to `exitRNGScope`.

```
    // [[Rcpp::register]]
    unsigned long exitRNGScope() {
        RNGScopeCounter--;
        if (RNGScopeCounter == 0) PutRNGstate();
        return RNGScopeCounter ;
    }
```

The problem is, because of interruption, we never get to `exitRNGScope`, so that when `RcppRNGs` calls `enterRNGScope` it is left to believe that is no need to call `GetRNGstate` so the seed is not handled properly.

Maybe `loop_apply` should call `checkUserInterrupt` but I'm not sure this would entirely fix the issue.

Comment: Will `loop_apply` even see the interrupt? Most of the time is going to be spent in `f`, which I think is why "stop" already works.

Comment: That's my concern too. which is why I believe this is an Rcpp bug. see https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/241

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug report.

Comment: Sure. I'll see what I can do in terms of offering a fix in Rcpp.

Comment: According to Dirk this is user error. So I probably won't use my time to fix this in Rcpp. I'll do it in Rcpp11 and Rcpp14 however as I believe this is a bug.

Comment: Romain, as I just told you over in the [issue ticket you filed](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/241), you misread what I said and you are extrapolating the wrong way.  This question here seems like a pretty clear case of user error to me; fixing this in Rcpp would be nice. To me, this issue joins a long list of other things for which improvements would be equally welcome.

Comment: For more on that see the comment by @rawr above.

Comment: I'm not extrapolating, just quote your "user error" words, and therefore deciding that I'm not in the mood to fix it.

Comment: As for the comment from @rawr, I think that misses the point entirely. `RcppRNGs` does not call `PutRNGstate` upon exit as it is led to believe that it should not. So getting the same random numbers with `rnorm(3)` as the ones generated in `RcppRNGs`.

Comment: This is now fixed in Rcpp 0.11.4.2.